# CodeIgniter - Add social media profile via login

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, oauth, tankauth

I'm developing a CI application that, let's say for the purposes of this question, simply allows a user (registered through Tank Auth) to compile a list of their social media profiles (Facebook, Twitter, Google+, etc).

The process for adding a profile would be similar to signing into a site via one of the social networks by entering your username/email and password. However, instead of signing in to the site using this method, I simply want to save to the database the user's name/username as it appears on their profile and a link to the profile. Perhaps also some other data that I have yet to think of.

In other words, it would be like a one-time login to save data to the database.

I'm not sure if something like this is possible by modifying a library like this http://classpattern.com/oauth-login.html, or if I would have to handle each social network with their respective APIs, if they have one.

Comment: I advise you to use a library for each social network, since you will end up with a ton of different methods just to auth, fetch data and etc. Since each social network as it's own API. And btw this question seems to be offtopic since there will be many possible answers.

Comment: It seems like that would be the way to go. And how can a question be off-topic if the question is what sets the topic? Of course there could be multiple possible answers, that is what I often hope for.